# Using aria accessability roles in react js

Tags: html, select, accessibility, wai-aria

Im trying to make a react component usable by audio browsing. I'm using aria roles like list box and option. I'm trying to make my select box that is created from divs, act like a select box to the audio browser. Would these roles be the best for that

Example:

```
<div class="selector" role="listbox">
    <div class="option" role="option">
    <div class="option" role="option">
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason for not using a native select?

Comment: Yeah we wanted the nice type ahead autocomplete features from the react select. I've been learning more about WAI ARIA, and from what I've read using the 'roaming tab index' or aria-activedescendant techniques may be the best options.

Comment: As with all ARIA attributes, test them on all your target platforms. I have never tested these roles but your markup seems to conform with the ARIA specification

Comment: One thing I also noticed is if the style of the element goes from display: none to display: block, the screen reader will not be able to navigate down into it yet. But if I navigate up the dom tree and back down, the screen reader now sees the elements that were made visible. Maybe I need to notify the screen reader somehow??